Find the problem here: "could not deserialize" - Spring Boot JPA
Oracle DB, Spring Boot
The code works fine when I remove TipologiePareti from ImpiantiCisterne entity.
ImpiantiCisterne.java
public class ImpiantiCisterne implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2076312334896585170L;
    private BigDecimal id;
    private SigeSietabEntiSisme sigeSietabEntiSisme;
    private String edrc;
    private Byte nrImpianto;
    private BigDecimal nrTp;
    private Byte nrCisterna;
    private String nomeAssegnato;
    private Long capacita;
    private String sondaPresente;
    private String tipoParete;
    private BigDecimal livelloProdotto;
    private BigDecimal livelloAcqua;
    private BigDecimal volumeProdotto;
    private BigDecimal volumeAcqua;
    private Long temperatura;
    private String codCarburante;
    private Date dataUltAgg;
    private Date dataUltDisponLivelli;
    private Date dataUltErrSondaProdotto;
    private Date dataUltErrSondaAcqua;
    private BigDecimal percVolumeInsuff;
    private BigDecimal percVolumeOtt;
    private Long capacitaMax;
    private Long capacitaMin;
    private Long temperaturaMax;
    private Long temperaturaMin;
    private String attivo;
    private String matricola;
    private String accessori;
    private String tipoPareteDesc;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TIPOLOGIE_PARETI_ID", referencedColumnName = "TIPOLOGIE_PARETI_ID", nullable = false)
    private TipologiePareti tipologieParetiId;


    private Impianti impianti;

    public ImpiantiCisterne() {
    }



    public ImpiantiCisterne(BigDecimal id, SigeSietabEntiSisme sigeSietabEntiSisme, String edrc, Byte nrImpianto,
            BigDecimal nrTp, Byte nrCisterna, String nomeAssegnato, Long capacita, String sondaPresente, String tipoParete,
            BigDecimal livelloProdotto, BigDecimal livelloAcqua, BigDecimal volumeProdotto, BigDecimal volumeAcqua,
            Long temperatura, String codCarburante, Date dataUltAgg, Date dataUltDisponLivelli,
            Date dataUltErrSondaProdotto, Date dataUltErrSondaAcqua, BigDecimal percVolumeInsuff,
            BigDecimal percVolumeOtt, Long capacitaMax, Long capacitaMin, Long temperaturaMax, Long temperaturaMin,
            String attivo, String matricola, String accessori, Impianti impianti) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.sigeSietabEntiSisme = sigeSietabEntiSisme;
        this.edrc = edrc;
        this.nrImpianto = nrImpianto;
        this.nrTp = nrTp;
        this.nrCisterna = nrCisterna;
        this.nomeAssegnato = nomeAssegnato;
        this.capacita = capacita;
        this.sondaPresente = sondaPresente;
        this.tipoParete = tipoParete;
        this.livelloProdotto = livelloProdotto;
        this.livelloAcqua = livelloAcqua;
        this.volumeProdotto = volumeProdotto;
        this.volumeAcqua = volumeAcqua;
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
        this.codCarburante = codCarburante;
        this.dataUltAgg = dataUltAgg;
        this.dataUltDisponLivelli = dataUltDisponLivelli;
        this.dataUltErrSondaProdotto = dataUltErrSondaProdotto;
        this.dataUltErrSondaAcqua = dataUltErrSondaAcqua;
        this.percVolumeInsuff = percVolumeInsuff;
        this.percVolumeOtt = percVolumeOtt;
        this.capacitaMax = capacitaMax;
        this.capacitaMin = capacitaMin;
        this.temperaturaMax = temperaturaMax;
        this.temperaturaMin = temperaturaMin;
        this.attivo = attivo;
        this.matricola = matricola;
        this.accessori = accessori;
        this.impianti = impianti;
    }



    public ImpiantiCisterne(String edrc, Byte nrImpianto, Byte nrCisterna, BigDecimal id) {
        this.edrc = edrc;
        this.nrImpianto = nrImpianto;
        this.nrCisterna = nrCisterna;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ImpiantiCisterne(String edrc, Byte nrImpianto, Byte nrCisterna, BigDecimal id, SigeSietabEntiSisme sigeSietabEntiSisme, BigDecimal percVolumeInsuff,
            BigDecimal percVolumeOtt) {
        this.edrc = edrc;
        this.nrImpianto = nrImpianto;
        this.nrCisterna = nrCisterna;
        this.id = id;
        this.sigeSietabEntiSisme = sigeSietabEntiSisme;
        this.percVolumeInsuff = percVolumeInsuff;
        this.percVolumeOtt = percVolumeOtt;
    }

    public ImpiantiCisterne(String edrc, Byte nrImpianto, Byte nrCisterna, BigDecimal id, SigeSietabEntiSisme sigeSietabEntiSisme, String nomeAssegnato,
            Long capacita, String sondaPresente, String tipoParete, BigDecimal livelloProdotto, BigDecimal livelloAcqua,
            BigDecimal volumeProdotto, BigDecimal volumeAcqua, Long temperatura, Date dataUltAgg,
            Date dataUltDisponLivelli, Date dataUltErrSondaProdotto, Date dataUltErrSondaAcqua,
            BigDecimal percVolumeInsuff, BigDecimal percVolumeOtt, Long capacitaMax, Long capacitaMin,
            Long temperaturaMax, Long temperaturaMin) {
        this.edrc = edrc;
        this.nrImpianto = nrImpianto;
        this.nrCisterna = nrCisterna;
        this.id = id;
        this.sigeSietabEntiSisme = sigeSietabEntiSisme;
        this.nomeAssegnato = nomeAssegnato;
        this.capacita = capacita;
        this.sondaPresente = sondaPresente;
        this.tipoParete = tipoParete;
        this.livelloProdotto = livelloProdotto;
        this.livelloAcqua = livelloAcqua;
        this.volumeProdotto = volumeProdotto;
        this.volumeAcqua = volumeAcqua;
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
        this.dataUltAgg = dataUltAgg;
        this.dataUltDisponLivelli = dataUltDisponLivelli;
        this.dataUltErrSondaProdotto = dataUltErrSondaProdotto;
        this.dataUltErrSondaAcqua = dataUltErrSondaAcqua;
        this.percVolumeInsuff = percVolumeInsuff;
        this.percVolumeOtt = percVolumeOtt;
        this.capacitaMax = capacitaMax;
        this.capacitaMin = capacitaMin;
        this.temperaturaMax = temperaturaMax;
        this.temperaturaMin = temperaturaMin;

    }




    public ImpiantiCisterne(BigDecimal id, SigeSietabEntiSisme sigeSietabEntiSisme, String edrc, Byte nrImpianto,
            Byte nrCisterna, String nomeAssegnato, Long capacita, String sondaPresente, String tipoParete,
            BigDecimal livelloProdotto, BigDecimal livelloAcqua, BigDecimal volumeProdotto, BigDecimal volumeAcqua,
            Long temperatura, String codCarburante, Date dataUltAgg, Date dataUltDisponLivelli,
            Date dataUltErrSondaProdotto, Date dataUltErrSondaAcqua, BigDecimal percVolumeInsuff,
            BigDecimal percVolumeOtt, Long capacitaMax, Long capacitaMin, Long temperaturaMax, Long temperaturaMin,
            String attivo, String matricola, String accessori, Impianti impianti) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.sigeSietabEntiSisme = sigeSietabEntiSisme;
        this.edrc = edrc;
        this.nrImpianto = nrImpianto;
        this.nrCisterna = nrCisterna;
        this.nomeAssegnato = nomeAssegnato;
        this.capacita = capacita;
        this.sondaPresente = sondaPresente;
        this.tipoParete = tipoParete;
        this.livelloProdotto = livelloProdotto;
        this.livelloAcqua = livelloAcqua;
        this.volumeProdotto = volumeProdotto;
        this.volumeAcqua = volumeAcqua;
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
        this.codCarburante = codCarburante;
        this.dataUltAgg = dataUltAgg;
        this.dataUltDisponLivelli = dataUltDisponLivelli;
        this.dataUltErrSondaProdotto = dataUltErrSondaProdotto;
        this.dataUltErrSondaAcqua = dataUltErrSondaAcqua;
        this.percVolumeInsuff = percVolumeInsuff;
        this.percVolumeOtt = percVolumeOtt;
        this.capacitaMax = capacitaMax;
        this.capacitaMin = capacitaMin;
        this.temperaturaMax = temperaturaMax;
        this.temperaturaMin = temperaturaMin;
        this.attivo = attivo;
        this.matricola = matricola;
        this.accessori = accessori;
        this.impianti = impianti;
    }



    public ImpiantiCisterne(BigDecimal id, SigeSietabEntiSisme sigeSietabEntiSisme, String edrc, Byte nrImpianto,
            BigDecimal nrTp, Byte nrCisterna, String nomeAssegnato, Long capacita, String sondaPresente,
            String tipoParete, BigDecimal livelloProdotto, BigDecimal livelloAcqua, BigDecimal volumeProdotto,
            BigDecimal volumeAcqua, Long temperatura, String codCarburante, Date dataUltAgg, Date dataUltDisponLivelli,
            Date dataUltErrSondaProdotto, Date dataUltErrSondaAcqua, BigDecimal percVolumeInsuff,
            BigDecimal percVolumeOtt, Long capacitaMax, Long capacitaMin, Long temperaturaMax, Long temperaturaMin,
            String attivo, String matricola, String accessori, String tipoPareteDesc, Impianti impianti) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.sigeSietabEntiSisme = sigeSietabEntiSisme;
        this.edrc = edrc;
        this.nrImpianto = nrImpianto;
        this.nrTp = nrTp;
        this.nrCisterna = nrCisterna;
        this.nomeAssegnato = nomeAssegnato;
        this.capacita = capacita;
        this.sondaPresente = sondaPresente;
        this.tipoParete = tipoParete;
        this.livelloProdotto = livelloProdotto;
        this.livelloAcqua = livelloAcqua;
        this.volumeProdotto = volumeProdotto;
        this.volumeAcqua = volumeAcqua;
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
        this.codCarburante = codCarburante;
        this.dataUltAgg = dataUltAgg;
        this.dataUltDisponLivelli = dataUltDisponLivelli;
        this.dataUltErrSondaProdotto = dataUltErrSondaProdotto;
        this.dataUltErrSondaAcqua = dataUltErrSondaAcqua;
        this.percVolumeInsuff = percVolumeInsuff;
        this.percVolumeOtt = percVolumeOtt;
        this.capacitaMax = capacitaMax;
        this.capacitaMin = capacitaMin;
        this.temperaturaMax = temperaturaMax;
        this.temperaturaMin = temperaturaMin;
        this.attivo = attivo;
        this.matricola = matricola;
        this.accessori = accessori;
        this.tipoPareteDesc = tipoPareteDesc;
        this.impianti = impianti;
    }



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "IMPIANTI_CISTERNE_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "IMPIANTI_CISTERNE_SEQ", sequenceName = "IMPIANTI_CISTERNE_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 30, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "EDRC", nullable = false, length = 5)
    public String getEdrc() {
        return this.edrc;
    }

    public void setEdrc(String edrc) {
        this.edrc = edrc;
    }

    @Column(name = "NR_IMPIANTO", nullable = false, precision = 2, scale = 0)
    public Byte getNrImpianto() {
        return this.nrImpianto;
    }

    public void setNrImpianto(Byte nrImpianto) {
        this.nrImpianto = nrImpianto;
    }

    @Column(name = "NR_CISTERNA", nullable = false, precision = 2, scale = 0)
    public Byte getNrCisterna() {
        return this.nrCisterna;
    }

    public void setNrCisterna(Byte nrCisterna) {
        this.nrCisterna = nrCisterna;
    }

    @Column(name = "NOME_ASSEGNATO", length = 64)
    public String getNomeAssegnato() {
        return this.nomeAssegnato;
    }

    public void setNomeAssegnato(String nomeAssegnato) {
        this.nomeAssegnato = nomeAssegnato;
    }

    @Column(name = "CAPACITA", precision = 12, scale = 2)
    public Long getCapacita() {
        return this.capacita;
    }

    public void setCapacita(Long capacita) {
        this.capacita = capacita;
    }

    @Column(name = "SONDA_PRESENTE", length = 1)
    public String getSondaPresente() {
        return this.sondaPresente;
    }

    public void setSondaPresente(String sondaPresente) {
        this.sondaPresente = sondaPresente;
    }

    @Column(name = "TIPO_PARETE", length = 1)
    public String getTipoParete() {
        return this.tipoParete;
    }

    public void setTipoParete(String tipoParete) {
        this.tipoParete = tipoParete;
    }

    @Column(name = "LIVELLO_PRODOTTO", precision = 6, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getLivelloProdotto() {
        return this.livelloProdotto;
    }

    public void setLivelloProdotto(BigDecimal livelloProdotto) {
        this.livelloProdotto = livelloProdotto;
    }

    @Column(name = "LIVELLO_ACQUA", precision = 6, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getLivelloAcqua() {
        return this.livelloAcqua;
    }

    public void setLivelloAcqua(BigDecimal livelloAcqua) {
        this.livelloAcqua = livelloAcqua;
    }

    @Column(name = "VOLUME_PRODOTTO", precision = 12, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getVolumeProdotto() {
        return this.volumeProdotto;
    }

    public void setVolumeProdotto(BigDecimal volumeProdotto) {
        this.volumeProdotto = volumeProdotto;
    }

    @Column(name = "VOLUME_ACQUA", precision = 12, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getVolumeAcqua() {
        return this.volumeAcqua;
    }

    public void setVolumeAcqua(BigDecimal volumeAcqua) {
        this.volumeAcqua = volumeAcqua;
    }

    @Column(name = "TEMPERATURA", precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public Long getTemperatura() {
        return this.temperatura;
    }

    public void setTemperatura(Long temperatura) {
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATA_ULT_AGG", length = 7)
    public Date getDataUltAgg() {
        return this.dataUltAgg;
    }

    public void setDataUltAgg(Date dataUltAgg) {
        this.dataUltAgg = dataUltAgg;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATA_ULT_DISPON_LIVELLI", length = 7)
    public Date getDataUltDisponLivelli() {
        return this.dataUltDisponLivelli;
    }

    public void setDataUltDisponLivelli(Date dataUltDisponLivelli) {
        this.dataUltDisponLivelli = dataUltDisponLivelli;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATA_ULT_ERR_SONDA_PRODOTTO", length = 7)
    public Date getDataUltErrSondaProdotto() {
        return this.dataUltErrSondaProdotto;
    }

    public void setDataUltErrSondaProdotto(Date dataUltErrSondaProdotto) {
        this.dataUltErrSondaProdotto = dataUltErrSondaProdotto;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATA_ULT_ERR_SONDA_ACQUA", length = 7)
    public Date getDataUltErrSondaAcqua() {
        return this.dataUltErrSondaAcqua;
    }

    public void setDataUltErrSondaAcqua(Date dataUltErrSondaAcqua) {
        this.dataUltErrSondaAcqua = dataUltErrSondaAcqua;
    }

    @Column(name = "PERC_VOLUME_INSUFF", nullable = false, precision = 2, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getPercVolumeInsuff() {
        return this.percVolumeInsuff;
    }

    public void setPercVolumeInsuff(BigDecimal percVolumeInsuff) {
        this.percVolumeInsuff = percVolumeInsuff;
    }

    @Column(name = "PERC_VOLUME_OTT", nullable = false, precision = 2, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getPercVolumeOtt() {
        return this.percVolumeOtt;
    }

    public void setPercVolumeOtt(BigDecimal percVolumeOtt) {
        this.percVolumeOtt = percVolumeOtt;
    }


    @Column(name = "COD_CARBURANTE", length = 3)
    public String getCodCarburante() {
        return codCarburante;
    }

    public void setCodCarburante(String codCarburante) {
        this.codCarburante = codCarburante;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EDRC", referencedColumnName = "ENTE_SISME", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public SigeSietabEntiSisme getSigeSietabEntiSisme() {
        return this.sigeSietabEntiSisme;
    }

    public void setSigeSietabEntiSisme(SigeSietabEntiSisme sigeSietabEntiSisme) {
        this.sigeSietabEntiSisme = sigeSietabEntiSisme;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({ //NOSONAR
            @JoinColumn(name = "EDRC", referencedColumnName = "EDRC", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NR_IMPIANTO", referencedColumnName = "NR_IMPIANTO", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Impianti getImpianti() {
        return this.impianti;
    }

    public void setImpianti(Impianti impianti) {
        this.impianti = impianti;
    }

    @Column(name = "CAPACITA_MAX", precision = 12, scale = 0)
    public Long getCapacitaMax() {
        return capacitaMax;
    }

    public void setCapacitaMax(Long capacitaMax) {
        this.capacitaMax = capacitaMax;
    }

    @Column(name = "CAPACITA_MIN", precision = 12, scale = 0)
    public Long getCapacitaMin() {
        return capacitaMin;
    }
    public void setCapacitaMin(Long capacitaMin) {
        this.capacitaMin = capacitaMin;
    }

    @Column(name = "TEMPERATURA_MAX", precision = 4, scale = 0)
    public Long getTemperaturaMax() {
        return temperaturaMax;
    }

    public void setTemperaturaMax(Long temperaturaMax) {
        this.temperaturaMax = temperaturaMax;
    }

    @Column(name = "TEMPERATURA_MIN", precision = 4, scale = 0)
    public Long getTemperaturaMin() {
        return temperaturaMin;
    }
    public void setTemperaturaMin(Long temperaturaMin) {
        this.temperaturaMin = temperaturaMin;
    }

    @Column(name = "ATTIVO", length = 1)
    public String getAttivo() {
        return attivo;
    }

    public void setAttivo(String attivo) {
        this.attivo = attivo;
    }

    @Column(name = "MATRICOLA", length = 32)
    public String getMatricola() {
        return matricola;
    }

    public void setMatricola(String matricola) {
        this.matricola = matricola;
    }

    @Column(name = "ACCESSORI", length = 1024)
    public String getAccessori() {
        return accessori;
    }

    public void setAccessori(String accessori) {
        this.accessori = accessori;
    }



    @Column(name = "NR_TP")
    public BigDecimal getNrTp() {
        return nrTp;
    }
    public void setNrTp(BigDecimal nrTp) {
        this.nrTp = nrTp;
    }

    @Column(name = "TIPO_PARETE_DESC", length = 1024)
    public String getTipoPareteDesc() {
        return tipoPareteDesc;
    }
    public void setTipoPareteDesc(String tipoPareteDesc) {
        this.tipoPareteDesc = tipoPareteDesc;
    }

    public TipologiePareti getTipologieParetiId() {
        return tipologieParetiId;
    }

    public void setTipologieParetiId(TipologiePareti tipologieParetiId) {
        this.tipologieParetiId = tipologieParetiId;
    }
}

TipologiePareti.java
public class TipologiePareti implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2193604710005896738L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "TIPOLOGIE_PARETI_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TIPOLOGIE_PARETI_SEQ", sequenceName = "TIPOLOGIE_PARETI_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "TIPOLOGIE_PARETI_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 4)
    private BigDecimal tipologieParetiId;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIZIONE", length = 1024)
    private String descrizione;

    @Column(name = "COD_PARETE")
    private String codParete;

    public TipologiePareti() {

    }

    public TipologiePareti(BigDecimal tipologieParetiId, String descrizione, String codParete) {
        this.tipologieParetiId = tipologieParetiId;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.codParete = codParete;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTipologieParetiId() {
        return tipologieParetiId;
    }

    public void setTipologieParetiId(BigDecimal tipologieParetiId) {
        this.tipologieParetiId = tipologieParetiId;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public String getCodParete() {
        return codParete;
    }

    public void setCodParete(String codParete) {
        this.codParete = codParete;
    }
}

As soon as I run this query:
impiantiCisterneRepository.getAllImpiantiCisterne(filter.getEdrc(), filter.getNrImpianto().byteValue());

Which is:
@Query("SELECT i FROM ImpiantiCisterne i where 1=1 and i.edrc = :edrc and i.nrImpianto=:nrImpianto order by i.nrCisterna" )
List<ImpiantiCisterne> getAllImpiantiCisterne( @Param("edrc") String edrc,@Param("nrImpianto") Byte nrImpianto);

I get the following error:
17:09:46.340 [i.d.e.v.service.impl.ImpiantiService] ERROR - ImpiantiService.getSchedaImpianto
17:09:46.342 [i.d.e.v.service.impl.ImpiantiService] ERROR - could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:353)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy231.getAllImpiantiCisterne(Unknown Source)
at it.dacinformatica.efwm.v1.service.impl.ImpiantiService.getSchedaImpianto(ImpiantiService.java:2548)
What's wrong?

You have annotations on both the properties and the accessor methods - try putting them all on one or the other. JPA has rules on how annotations are to be picked up that are troublesome as it can cause them to be ignored; its best not to mix and match unless you have a strong reason to.
